# Why did one of my squad members disappear?

Tags: mass-effect

So, I'm playing the original Mass Effect for the first time (don't ask), and I was doing the Rogue VI mission on Luna. I decided to throw Kaidan a bone and took him and Garrus with me.

I just completed the first bunker, left, and noticed that Kaidan is no longer in my party. Or anywhere. I went back inside the bunker and he's not there either (the map only has two marks, for myself and Garrus). His name and health don't appear in the lower left. Even the equipment and squad menus on the start menu don't show him.

Is this something that's supposed to happen? Or a glitch? There was no notification (at least, not that I noticed), and it's never happened to me before, so I'm pretty confused. I googled it and found some people talking about the same thing, but there was nothing very enlightening.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: Sure sounds like a weird glitch - never happened to me in a few runs.

Comment: There's no perma-death in Mass Effect except for [spoilers], so there's no reason for Kaiden to be missing.  The best explanation I can offer is that he went down, but you didn't clear the area before moving on to the outside.

Comment: @Kareen Is there a particular reason you decided to exclude the game title from the question? I can understand the changes, except for that. Doesn't not including it simply make the question more ambiguous?

Comment: @KevinMills Putting the game name in the question title is redundant because of the question tag. This is Arqade convention, and it makes sense - if you look at your tab title, the tag name is placed before the question title, so it's already "mass effect - Why did [...]". The tags are also fairly prominently placed on the home page and in the question list.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be some kind of glitch. There are only a handful of permanent deaths that occur in the first Mass Effect game, and none of these deaths occur during the Rogue VI mission.

You'll probably want to either load an earlier save game or edit your save game using the gibbed editor to restore Kaiden back to the land of the living.

Comment: pffft, why would you want to revive kaiden.  seems like a great glitch to me

Comment: beats me - out of ME1 deaths the only one I'd care about is Wrex and you don't even get him as a team mate for the other two...

Answer (score 1):

The same happened to me. If you have a party member die, and do not clear the area before getting too far from the body. Or do not wait after the combat for them to revive, they can disappear. 
If you go back to the ship and select your party again they come back. It's not a permanent death situation.

Answer (score 0):

This actually happened to me on the same mission, but with Wrex. He got knocked down against a wall by an explosion and when I revived him, he went to stand up in the wall. Then he, his name, and his power and weapon wheel disappeared as well. I believe it to be a glitch.